# Optimizing a loss function that ignores certain label values

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, loss-function

I'm writing a binary classifier for sparse input data, and I would like to regard inputs of 0 as an indication that data does not exist rather than an indication that the value is affirmatively 0. I was originally using `tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(...))`, but it penalized false positives too harshly.

I successfully wrote a loss function, shown below, that provides the behavior I would like, but it is multiple orders of magnitude slower and I need to find a way to steal some performance back.

```py
def loss(labels, logits):
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, shape=(-1,))
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, shape=(-1,))
    pairs = tf.stack([labels, logits], axis=1)

    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.map_fn(
        lambda x: tf.cond(
            x[0] < x[1],  # x[0] is in {0,1} and x[1] is in (0,1)
            lambda: 0.0,  # thus the condition is true iff x[0] == 0
            lambda: tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                labels=x[0],
                logits=x[1])),
        pairs))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've come up with a solution. It occurred to me that I didn't actually need to normalize against the number of labels to get the mean rather than just the sum, so created a `{0,1}` mask out of the condition by running the comparison and casting the result to a float. I then used matrix multiplication to take the dot product of the `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(...)` result with this mask, so that values where the condition is true are added to the sum and values where the condition is false are canceled by multiplying them with zero.

This may not be the best solution, and I'll be leaving the question open for a while in case someone can suggest a better alternative in terms of being more idiomatic or performance benefits, but it offers sufficient performance for my current needs.

```py
def loss(labels, logits):
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, shape=(-1,))
    logits = tf.reshape(logits, shape=(-1,))
    output = tf.reshape(
        tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels=labels,
            logits=logits),
        shape=(1, -1))

    mask = tf.reshape(
        tf.cast(labels > logits, tf.float32),  # True iff label==1
        shape=(-1, 1))

    return tf.matmul(output, mask)
```